# Unable to Update Github desktop for Linux (Error: 429 Too Many Requests)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, github, linux-mint, github-desktop

When I am trying to update Github Desktop through my update manager it giving an error

```
Failed to fetch https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/any/dists/any/InRelease 

429 Too Many Requests [IP: 54.183.216.24 443]Some index files failed to download. 

They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

[image: img_Github_Desktop]

How to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem is Github desktop's hosting exceeded its monthly bandwidth allocation. That's why we are getting `429 Too Many Requests` error.

You can check it from https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/any/dists/any/InRelease

> How to resolve :

A. Remove `packagecloud-shiftky-desktop.list` from `sources.list.d`

1. Goto  `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory
2. Right-click inside the directory and choose `Open as Root` option
3. Enter your login credential to Authenticate
4. Select `packagecloud-shiftky-desktop.list` file and delete it
5. Now check the update again.

> OR

B. Through the Update Manager

1. Open your Update Manager and find the `Additional Repositories` option

( **Note :** different Linux distributions has different settings, in Linux Mint, Update Manager -> Edit -> Software Sources -> Additional Repositories)

2. Uncheck `packagecloud.io/any` option -> Ok

[image: img_software_sources]

> Update

As long as, automatic update not available, the best way to check for the update is, download the latest release from its Github release page
https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop/releases